# Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, truffle, testing

```
const config = require('../truffle-config.js');
const token_parameters = require('../token_parameters.json');
const ExampleToken = artifacts.require('ExampleToken');

module.exports = function(deployer, network, accounts) {
  const networkId = config.networks[network.replace(/-fork$/, '')].network_id;
  const deploymentAddress = accounts[0];
  console.log('Deployment address: ' + accounts[0]);
  deployer.deploy(
    ExampleToken,
    token_parameters[networkId].name,
    token_parameters[networkId].symbol,
    token_parameters[networkId].initialAddress,
    web3.utils.toWei(token_parameters[networkId].totalSupply),
    { from: deploymentAddress, gas: 1500000 },
  );
};
```

how do I fix below error?

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
    at module.exports (/Users/*/*/*/*/2_deploy_token.js:12:33)
    at Migration._load (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/migrate/Migration.js:54:1)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

Comment: Does `../token_parameters.json` exist, and does it have a property for the network ID?

Comment: I wonder when will ethereum programmers realize that requiring a json is **wrong**...

Comment: @Morten: That's not the point, you simply don't `require('xxx.json')`! You read it as a file, and then `JSON.parse` its contents.

Comment: yeah it does @Morten

Comment: @goodvibration worked :)